# How can i set the viewlist width to fitted size when the viewlist items been loaded in the javascript html5 metro app

Tags: javascript, html, listview, user-interface, microsoft-metro

I have developed a metro app by using javascript+html5, in the UI have a listview, but the listview width can not be set to the fitted size, i do not went to set width to a fixed size because i don't know how many items will be loaded. I have try to set listview width to auto size but no way.

PS.
I fund a method that can refresh the listview width to fitted size, when the mouse hover on the back button the UI refresh immediately then listview automatic set the width to fitted size, so how can i refresh the UI when XHR have been worked.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the ListView, there is not need to set the size to accommodate all the items -- it will virtualize the data within the viewport that you give it and let the user scroll. However, it does need a size. You can set the size to fill the container as you see fit using normal CSS rules.

Comment: thanks for reply, my UI use a grid, the following is my css

#myGrid {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display: -ms-grid;
 -ms-grid-columns: auto auto auto;
 -ms-grid-rows: 129px 1fr;
 overflow-x: auto;
 overflow-y:hidden
}

#listview{
 width: auto;
 height: 80%;
 position: relative;
        -ms-grid-row: 2;
 -ms-grid-column: 1;
 margin-top: 30px;
 margin-left: 50px;
}

Comment: you shouldn't need the width/height -- it'll just fill the row& grid appropriately. Ditty with the margin; just put the rows/columns as the margin.

I use layouts like this all the time in my app -- works great.